# How to simulate out of gas events on a private blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, gas, contract-debugging, out-of-gas, gas-limit

I want to get the error message "Intrinsic gas too low" during a eth.sendTransaction call.

Is it possible to simulate the condition of having run out of gas in a private blockchain scenario?

Can someone please point the way to understand this and other possible edge cases?

*EDIT* -

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether")
>   21
>
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], gas:100000, value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
>
> miner.start(1); admin.sleepBlocks(1); miner.stop();
>
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether")
>   21

Why did my coinbase account balance remain 21?

Comment: lets call it `resend` not `refill`

Comment: If your question is about how to simulate out of gas events on a private blockchain, please [revise your question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/2882/edit) inkluding the title. it can be reopened any time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resend your transaction specifying a higher gas amount.

If you omit the `gas` parameter from the `eth.sendTransaction(...)` call, a default of 21000 is used for plain vanilla transactions.

To simulate running out of gas:

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], gas:21000, value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
"0xcff42095692bb7ae72bbebbdbc7e177780e3d55859b96d7bfe561c695462d569"

> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], gas:1000, value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
Intrinsic gas too low
    at InvalidResponse (<anonymous>:-81662:-108)
    at send (<anonymous>:-156322:-108)
    at sendTransaction (<anonymous>:-133322:-108)
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], gas:100000, value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
"0x03e337d75ed319b15029bdca7c491e48acde4cfa44594f50df4cfb7aac5d7f53"
```

When you send your transaction, you should get a transaction hash.

You may have to leave your miner running for a few more blocks. Remove your `admin.sleepBlocks(1); miner.stop();` statement.

If the transaction is successful, you will get something like the following result - the first call to `eth.getTransaction(...)` shows the transaction has not been mined yet (blockNumber is null). The second call shows the mined transaction (blockNumber is 1476). After this, your account should have the amount deducted.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], gas:100000, value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
I0412 23:36:08.702030   21319 xeth.go:1028] Tx(0x511ac8d69452f0791b57ab62e7c5261119463696c01ed81fb1e58d637d46cab5) to: 0x043f7fdc6e789060bfad91f7bba100d20a1cdf18
"0x511ac8d69452f0791b57ab62e7c5261119463696c01ed81fb1e58d637d46cab5"
> eth.getTransaction("I0412 23:36:18.881647   21319 worker.go:348]   Mined block (#1475 / 37440f0d). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
VM STAT 0 OPs
I0412 23:36:18.882734   21319 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 1476 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.023896ms
VM STAT 0 OPs
I0412 23:36:18.883282   21319 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 1476 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 488.218µs
0x511ac8d69452f0791b57ab62e7c5261119463696c01ed81fb1e58d637d46cab5")
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x8d15cd39bdb00d5362775002c342c168ee707400",
  gas: 100000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x511ac8d69452f0791b57ab62e7c5261119463696c01ed81fb1e58d637d46cab5",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 4,
  to: "0x043f7fdc6e789060bfad91f7bba100d20a1cdf18",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 10000000000000000000
}
> I0412 23:36:23.527844   21319 worker.go:348]   Mined block (#1476 / ca7817a9). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0412 23:36:23.528429   21319 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 1477 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 505.461µs
I0412 23:36:23.528831   21319 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 1477 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 312.822µs
> eth.getTransaction("0x511ac8d69452f0791b57ab62e7c5261119463696c01ed81fb1e58d637d46cab5")
{
  blockHash: "0xca7817a90043b4c069e581d3ceb9bae0d147cd26f10a439410909d06fdaac5d0",
  blockNumber: 1476,
  from: "0x8d15cd39bdb00d5362775002c342c168ee707400",
  gas: 100000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x511ac8d69452f0791b57ab62e7c5261119463696c01ed81fb1e58d637d46cab5",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 4,
  to: "0x043f7fdc6e789060bfad91f7bba100d20a1cdf18",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 10000000000000000000
}
```

You should also see `commit new work on block 1476 with 1 txs & 0 uncles` when your transaction is included in the mined block.